# How should invalid edits to reopen votes be handled by reviewers?

Tags: support, review-queues, reopen-closed

After never spending time reviewing reopen votes since I've had access, I took my first swing at it this evening since I had some time to kill.

One of the reopen votes (https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/30313510) I was given a chance to review was edited by the asker to include their answer prior to being flagged to be reopened.

Normally I would add a comment on the question requesting the asker to add their update as an answer, but that's not possible while it's closed.

I assume moderators can do this, but I don't believe I can given my current rep.

Besides that, it's ridiculous that reviewers cannot see the post marked as the duplicate as that being reviewed on the review page. I know I can open the full current post, but that shouldn't be necessary when all of the rest of the question is available in the review.

Comment: "Besides that, it's ridiculous that reviewers cannot see the post marked as the duplicate as that being reviewed on the review page." What do you mean? The title says [duplicate] and there's a `Duplicate` pill which can be clicked to immediately view the duplicate within the queue.

Comment: @HenryEcker - Not as I see on the review page. Maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was given a chance to review was edited by the asker to include their answer prior to being flagged to be reopened.

No. The post was added to the review queue in [Revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69925796/2) by [0abc0cba0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14951535/0abc0cba0). An hour and a half *after* the post was added to the Reopen queue a solution was posted within the question body in [Revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69925796/4) by [0abc0cba0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14951535/0abc0cba0).

This can be seen in post [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69925796/revisions). Notice the indicator next to Revision 2 "Added to review":

[image: Image of post revisions; Revision 2 with "Added to review" indicator circled in red]

The edit which was used to trigger the reopen process ([Revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69925796/2) by [0abc0cba0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14951535/0abc0cba0)) specifically clarified that certain methods could not be used:

> I cant't use `mat.at<float>` or `.step1()`.

This was likely added to clarify why the duplicate does not apply and that is why the OP choose to indicate that the "edit resolve[d] the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening."

---

> Normally I would add a comment on the question requesting the asker to add their update as an answer, but that's not possible while it's closed.

In the meantime, I would rollback the edit so the answer is not in the question field. I would also add a comment letting the user know that they should not be adding an answer in their question. It is my preference to handle as many issues as possible when going through review queue, even if such actions would extend beyond the confines of a particular queue.

However, the only task at hand in the Reopen queue is to determine if this question (in its current state) should or should not remain closed. In the case of a duplicate, this also requires checking if the current post is or is not a duplicate of the linked duplicate. This may require some subject matter knowledge and such reviews should be skipped when unable to determine if the duplicate applies.

In this particular case, the primary reopen reason is an edit clarifying the constraints on the question. Making the current review decision based largely on if these additional constraints are enough to make the duplicate no longer apply.

Only *if* the question is reopened on its own merit (not with the inclusion of the answer that should not be in the question field) can the question receive an answer by OP or others.

---

> Besides that, it's ridiculous that reviewers cannot see the post marked as the duplicate as that being reviewed on the review page.

There are a few visual indicators that a question is closed as a duplicate.

[image: Image of Reopen Queue showing duplicate question indicators circled in red]

Namely, (1) the close reason banner, (2) the [duplicate] keyword appended to the title, and (3) the button labeled "Duplicate" which can be clicked to view the linked duplicate.

Comment: I saw it was flagged as duplicate, but missed the `duplicate` tab that is shown in this case since it was my first duplicate. I can edit my question to remove that part, but it only matters if your answer is edited also

Comment: I also don't see an option to rollback the edits. Probably missing something obvious but this is new to me

Comment: Edit rollbacks need to be done in the standard way via post  [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69925796/revisions). To be clear, rolling back the edit and indicating to the user why they should not add answers to the question is a bit beyond the scope of the Reopen review queue. This would require opening a few windows and doing more than _just_ determining if a question should or should not be reopened. However, personally, I prefer to handle as many of the issues with a post as possible when I come across it.